# Understanding the unit of work pattern

Tags: c#, unit-of-work

in my new c# project i want to implement the unit of work pattern.

According to [Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) a unit if work keeps track of all changes to your corresponding objects (newly created, dirty and removed objects). Other implementations like this one [jgauffin - ado.net the right way](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/522226/ADO-NET-cplustheplusrightplusway) use the unit of work "just" for transaction management. 
So a unit of work after Fowler is initialized at the start of the application and is kept in memory.
The "other" unit of work is only used for transactions and is disposed afterwards.

Why are these approaches so different?
Is there a go-to-implementation?

Thx in advance

Comment: It's a pattern and can be customized according to the need based on the project requirements.

Comment: Downvoters, please comment on why you are burying this question. While it might be better suited for [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) because it does not contain any code directly, it is still a valid question about coding techniques and shows effort through research. People, and especially new members like here, might not be aware of this other site and leaving their questions in a bad shape like this is not improving the situation ;)

Comment: Thx. Indeed i would like to know, why my question is downvoted (i still think it is a valid question). I didn't knew that there is programmers stackexchange.

Answer (score 4):

> a unit of work after Fowler is initialized at the start of the application and is kept in memory

No, it's not:

> [Folwer] A Unit of Work keeps track of everything you do **during a business transaction** that can affect the database.

Something like "create the invoice and invoice lines for this order" is done using one unit of work instance. This UoW is disposed after committing.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but i don't think that you are right. You are describing the behaviour of the "other" unit of work. Fowler's implementation uses registration methods for objects (in the unit of work). Objects uses these methods to let the unit of work know if they are altered, removed or newly created. So there is one current unit of work in memory as long as you are working with these objects. Nevertheless all "newer" uow implementations don't use these registration methods. Is there a reason?

Comment: @OlBoozeroony no, that's your interpretation, which is wrong. The UoW presented by Fowler has those method to add/update/delete records that belong together in one transaction, not one application.

Comment: Thx for the discussing. We are coming closer to my understanding problem ... Fowler is using the register-methods in the object property setter. So after an object gets changed it is marked as dirty in the uow. If i don't want to execute a transaction after every data change i need to have the responsible uow in memory, don't i? In an EF project the dataset would do this job, but without EF Fowler suggests that the uow keeps track of changed data.